# My sql:how to use Wildcard in Subquery?

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like

example:

```
SELECT country 
FROM data
WHERE city LIKE 
(SELECT LEFT ('jakartada',7));
```

it's working nicely but if i give delimiter with value:4 ,i must give wildcard 
like this ---> "%string%"  ,where i can give wildcard in the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern.

```
Character   Description
%           Matches any number of characters, even zero characters
_           Matches exactly one character
\%          Matches one “%” character
\_          Matches one “_” character
```

does this query help you?

```
SELECT country 
FROM data
WHERE city LIKE CONCAT ('%', (SELECT LEFT ('jakartada',7)), '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

why you using sub query?

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE city LIKE 'jakar%'
```

Comment: i wanna make prediction input feature in my program,and simple/easiest way is using this query than make complex method in java